# Bigcartel Api get remaining items in Stock

Tags: javascript, bigcartel

Working on a Custom Big Cartel theme and I am almost done, the only part that doesn't work is when a user updates the number of products in their cart, they can set the number to a value greater than the remaining stock. Using the Big cartel API it has variable called Product with a var

```
 product.options-   Returns all of the options of a product whether they are 
 sold out or not.
```

I then loop through all the options for one product like so

```
  Product.find(permalink, function(product) {
  console.log("I found " + product.name + "!");
var len=(product.options.length);
console.log(len);
  for(var i = 0; i<len;i++){
      console.log((product.options[i])); 
  }
});
```

The "Option" object, according to the API has a field

```
          option.quantity   Returns the quantity left in stock for an option.
```

Well when I examine the object that I get from the loop it prints

```
 Object {id: 153343298, name: "Small", price: 30, sold_out: false, has_custom_price: false}
```

And there is no "quantity" field. Here is a link to the API documentation, does anyone have any idea?
[Big Cartel API Docs](https://help.bigcartel.com/developers/themes/#product-1)

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer, by default when you click the checkout button on the BigCartel 'Cart.html' page, the element looks like this

```
<form method="post" action="/cart">
<ul class="plain_list">
   ... items in cart 
 </ul>
<p class="subtotal">
  ... 
</p>
<button type="submit" name="checkout" title="Checkout">Checkout</button>
</form>
```

It sumbits a post request that automatically checks if any item quantity in your cart is greater than the remaining stock. The element it generates to display the error message looks has the classes

```
<ul class="unstyled errors">
       <!-- Error Message here-->                   
        </ul>
```

I couldn't see this because my custom CSS blocked the element.